# How to attach OSDisk and change OSProfile for Azure VM

Tags: azure, operating-system, certificate, virtual-machine, disk

I am setting up a VM restoration pipeline. It looks like this:

I Copy the OS disk

```
$diskConfig = New-AzureRmDiskConfig -AccountType $storageType `
    -Location $snapshot.Location -SourceResourceId $snapshot.Id -CreateOption Copy
$disk = New-AzureRmDisk -Disk $diskConfig -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -DiskName $diskName
```

I then Attach it to my VM like so:

```
$vmConfig = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $virtualMachineName `
    -VMSize $virtualMachineSize
$vmConfig = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM `
    $vmConfig -ManagedDiskId $disk.Id -CreateOption Attach -Windows
```

However I also want to indirectly modify the `OSProfile` property of the VM by binding a certificate to it as I am following [this guide by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-secure-web-server). I do:

```
$vmConfig = Add-AzureRmVMSecret -VM $vmConfig -SourceVaultId $vaultId `
    -CertificateStore $certificateStore -CertificateUrl $certificateUrl
```

And now when I try to finalize the creation by

```
New-AzureRmVM -VM $vmConfig -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location
```

I get an error:

```
New-AzureRmVM : Parameter 'osProfile' is not allowed.
```

I am aware that it modifies `OSProfile.Secrets` (that is - adds a new record to the list), but there is a restriction that I cannot edit it whatsover. I also tried doing it by creating a VM first and then adding those `Secrets`, but it gives me the almost the same error

```
Update-AzureRmVM : Changing property 'osProfile' is not allowed.
```

By the way, if I use `FromImage` instead of `Attach`, I get error:

```
New-AzureRmVM : Cannot specify user image overrides for a disk already defined in the specified image reference.
```

**How can I solve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a powershell script that executes a powershell command (using `Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand`) on the VM which:

1. Retrieves certificates

   `Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -name (Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName).name`
2. Downloads and binds those certificates to IIS
3. Creates an ssl binding and assigns it to https binding

   `Get-ChildItem cert:\localmachine\My | New-Item -Path IIS:\SslBindings\!443`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this error means that you are trying to use existing disk to create vm. you cannot modify the os settings in this case. only when creating from new disk.

Comment: But I did copy it, didn't I? I would hope it would be able to be handled as new.

Comment: why does it matter if you copied it?

Comment: Well, I guess, it doesn't. But is there, in that case, a different way to achieve what my mentioned tutorial of binding a certificate does?

Comment: use a new vm image?

Comment: I have a lot of programs installed and set up the way I need in that disk. I cannot create an empty disk. It would take days to install/setup everything.

Comment: well, i'm not necessary right, but i gave you my best guess. nothing os related (the things i've tried at least) can be changed after vm is created. since you are using an existing vhd this is pretty much the same case. also, you should be using automation to install software.

Comment: In the tutorial that I gave the link to (and I tested myself with new vm with newly created empty disk) - it works fine, so yes, you can change some things related to OS (that is - certificates which are in OSProfile.Secrets). The problem is, as far as I understand, the fact that the OS disk is bound, that disables the OSProfile settings, but I must edit them somehow...

Comment: can you elaborate? what i said is that you can only define those on deploy time from new vhd, not from copy, are you saying something else?

Answer (score 0):

Provision a new VM **from an image** that has the closest matching osProfile that you want. Go ahead and let it create a new OS disk.

After the VM is fully provisioned, go to the VM in Azure Portal and stop the VM. Then go to the `Disks` settings in the VM's menu and click `Swap OS Disk`. Pick your desired OS disk. Note: The disk you pick might have to closely match the size and type of the existing OS disk. I didn't test that.

osProfile will remain on the VM. Worked for me at least. Hope it helps someone else.